# I want to write the answer of a function in a text file

Tags: python

My assignment is to create a function that asks the name, age, sex, and city of the user. Afterward we have to create a text file from python and insert the answers given by the user in this form:

```
   ÂGE : (user answer) ANS
   SEXE : M/F
   VILLE :( user answer)
```

I decided to write my code like this:

```
nom=input("Quel est votre nom ?")
age=input(" Quel est votre age ?")
sex=input("Quel est votre sexe ? ")
ville=input("Où résidez-vous ?")


def asv(nom,age,sex,ville):
    n=str(nom)
    a=str(age)
    s=str(sex)
    v=str(ville)

    return(n,a,s,v)

    fichier=open("ASV.txt","w")
    #fichier.write("Âge :" ++ "ans") #This is where I need help
    fichier.close()
```

I cannot seem to understand how to write this. I did some research and most of them talk about loops, which I haven't seen yet.

Comment: I'd be sad in a world where Python is obsolete. Also, have you tried `fichier.write('Age: {}'.format(age))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to append the string form of your variable with the label you want.  For instance:

```
fichier.write("Âge :" + age)
fichier.write("SEXE :" + sex)
...
```

You never converted your input to any other values, so you still have them in string form.  You do not need to convert them.  Having a function merely to convert four input values to string is generally a waste of effort.

Also, make sure that you're using the correct variables.  For the code you've posted, I think you need only local variables:

```
def asv():
    nom=input("Quel est votre nom ?")
    age=input(" Quel est votre age ?")
    sex=input("Quel est votre sexe ? ")
    ville=input("Où résidez-vous ?")

    fichier=open("ASV.txt","w")
    fichier.write ...
    ...
```

---

EDIT after OP comment

Puis, employez une function.    Peut-etre ...

```
def ecriver(nom,age,sex,ville):
        fichier=open("ASV.txt","w")
        fichier.write ...
        ...

# Main program

nom=input("Quel est votre nom ?")
age=input(" Quel est votre age ?")
sex=input("Quel est votre sexe ? ")
ville=input("Où résidez-vous ?")

ecriver(nom,age,sex,ville)
```

I leave the remaining details to the student.

Comment: I would leave out the function. If not, remove the parameters.

Comment: Thanks; I forgot to delete them.  Yes, it would be good to delete the function, and do all of this in the main program.

Comment: Thank You. I will try your recommendation, sadly the teacher really wants us to use a function. Merci